# cakephp 3 missing route ocures

Tags: cakephp, routes

I have cakephp 3 aplication with social login plugin, hybridauth.
Sometimes works login over face and over google but sometimes i get error like these:

[image]

***In 'hybridauth' instructions there is line:
Note: When specifying loginRedirect URL for AuthComponent be sure to add 'plugin' => false (or appropiate plugin name) to the URL array.***

Probably i did something wrong in my appcontroller. It looks like:

```
$this->loadComponent('Auth', [
        'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
                'fields' => [
                    'username' => 'email',
                    'password' => 'password'
                ]
            ],
    'ADmad/HybridAuth.HybridAuth' => [
        // All keys shown below are defaults
        'fields' => [
            'provider' => 'provider',
            'openid_identifier' => 'openid_identifier',
            'email' => 'email'
        ],
        'profileModel' => 'ADmad/HybridAuth.SocialProfiles',
        'profileModelFkField' => 'user_id',

        // The URL Hybridauth lib should redirect to after authentication.
        // If no value is specified you are redirect to this plugin's
        // HybridAuthController::authenticated() which handles persisting
        // user info to AuthComponent and redirection.
        'hauth_return_to' => null
    ]
        ],
        'loginRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'index',
            'ADmad/HybridAuth.HybridAuth' => 'false'
            'plugin' => 'false'
        ],
        'logoutRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Users',
            'action' => 'login',
            'home'
        ]
    ]);
```

Like you can see i try to ad lines to main 'loginRedirect' but there is same problem again.

```
'ADmad/HybridAuth.HybridAuth' => 'false'
'plugin' => 'false'
```

any idea please?
Thank you.

Even i can login sometimes. randomly. 
And every time when i push face or google login i get session-Auth. I am authenticated, but routing brings me to error screen. 
And than i can change url to localhost/projectname/users/index and everything is ok, works.
i also tryed to add routes to routes.php:

```
$routes->connect('/Users/index', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'index']);
$routes->connect('/http://localhost/sebastus1/hybrid-auth/authenticated', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'index']);
```

***SOLUTION***

thanks to ndm. 
(string)'false' != (boolean)false

Comment: Take a closer look at your code and compare it to the docs, `'false' != false`. Also the `ADmad/HybridAuth.HybridAuth` entry shouldn't be there at all, that doesn't  make any sense.

Comment: i think you solved it. i logged in now few times without any problem. sometimes i dont understand what i am reading. ;)  'false' != false